# Passenger Permission denied on ubuntu 22.04 for ruby 3.2.1 rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

a 500 Internal server error is being generated, and it is specifically logged by nginx as:

```
 [alert] 817#817: *1 Error opening '/home/deploy/mapt/current/Passengerfile.json' for reading:  
Permission denied (errno=13); This error means that the  
Nginx worker process (PID 817, running as UID 33)  
does not have permission to access this file.  
Please read this page to learn how to fix this problem:
```

The [help page (generic link)](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/troubleshooting/?a=upon-accessing-the-web-app-nginx-reports-a-permission-denied-error) indicated in the error message [refers to changing permissions (targetted link)](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/troubleshooting/ruby/#upon-accessing-the-web-app-nginx-reports-a-permission-denied-error), but given the error and the non-existence of the file, is not illuminating.

This is a new-ish behaviour as it was never encountered and a `Passengerfile.json` has never been present in the application's current directory under previous versions.

The current stack has

Ruby 3.2.1
Rails 7.0.4.2
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.17
ubuntu 22.04

the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf` is set as follows:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
# passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

passenger_instance_registry_dir /var/run/passenger-instreg;
```

Where/what needs changing?

Answer (score 2):

`chmod o+x $HOME`  solved the issue

Something changed, recently I suspect, with passenger.  Why? no idea as `Passengerfile.json` is a new face to this individual.

Comment: THANK YOU. I have been pulling my hair out after following the GoRails guide for getting everything running on 22.04 and was just getting endless 500 errors and no Passenger app was ever shown as running. After running this command, everything is working!